# Universal database retrieval

Tags: c#, sql

I'm attempting to make a method that returns a ObservableCollection by providing a object type & a table name.

The method should use this information to make a ObservableCollection which retrieves all rows from table and puts it into the previous ObservableCollection with the desired object type.

```
public class DatabaseManager
{
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<object>> GetObjectsAsync(object object_name, string table_name)
    {
        Type type = object_name.GetType();
        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(type.GetProperties());
        ObservableCollection<object> oc = new ObservableCollection<object>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Constants.ConnectionString))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from " + table_name;

                using (SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        object x = new object();

                        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
                        {
                            // I want to create a universal object that i can add to my observable collection here.
                            object propValue = prop.GetValue(object_name, null);

                            // Code Here
                        }

                        oc.Add(x);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return oc;
    }
}
```

The goal is to make a method for getting a ObservableCollection from a Database Table with a none specific object type.

I would appreciate any help / recommendations, I might have the wrong mind set of how to do this, but if it is at all possible please tell me.

Comment: whats the point of observable collection if you are returning a new instance everytime?

Comment: Seems like you are attempting to create a minimized version of an ORM. My advise - use Dapper instead of re-inventing the wheel. It's free, it's built for speed by some smart people and my personal favorite micro-ORM.

Comment: @ZoharPeled why not use entity framework. Its built in. no 3rd party lib required

Comment: Keep in mind this is in a UWP project.

Comment: @Steve EF offers a lot more flexibility than Dapper. As the result, EF is much "heavier" than Dapper, especially in the complexity of its learning curve.

Comment: @Steve I simply prefer dapper... I've had a bad time working with early versions of EF and don't like it since. Dapper seems to get the job done but still giving the developer better control over the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is a statically typed language, so generally you cannot build an object without knowing its type. In other words, when you do this

```
object x = new object();
```

you literally get an object of type `System.Object`, with no additional properties.

There are two ways of working around this:

- **Use `dynamic` and [`ExpandoObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.7.2)** - this would let you add properties on the fly, but the resulting objects would need to be used as `dynamic`, or
- **Take the type of the object that will be produced by the query** - your code can "link" table name to objects stored in the table. If you decide to go this route, consider using a lightweight ORM library, such as StackExchange's [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Comment: How would i go about solving my task at hand if i were to go down the Dapper road. (I have never put a finger on dapper)

Comment: @AlexanderBruun Download the library (they have nuget packages available). Then check out [dapper tutorial](https://dapper-tutorial.net/query), they have many useful examples.

Comment: Appreciate the help mate, happy new year!